# How do I pass variables from the Parent class method to the a Child class method?

Tags: python

I've got a parent class and a child class. I want the child class to take the method from the parent class, perform a operation and apply it. What I'm trying to do is loop through a wordlist file in the parent class method `openWordlist()`, and for every word in that wordlist file, pass it to the child class method `scanDomain()` to perform an operation which is to loop through website directories that are available to the public.

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wordlistFile = ''
        self.word = ''
    
    def openWordlist(self):
        with open(self.wordlistFile, 'r') as suppliedWordlist:
            for word in suppliedWordlist:
                word = word.strip()
                self.word = word

class DirectoryScan(Main):
    def scanDomain(self):
        try:
            self.cleanURL = 'https://google.com' + self.word
            self.reqURL = requests.get(self.cleanURL)
            if self.reqURL.status_code == 200:
                print('Found: {self.cleanURL}')
            elif self.reqURL.status_code != 200:
                pass
        except InvalidURL:
                print(f'{self.targetURL} does NOT exist.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Main()
    d = DirectoryScan()
    directoryScan.openWordlist()
    directoryScan.scanDomain()
```

However, the result that I'm getting is just the `https://google.com/` back. Is there something wrong with the inheritance that I'm doing?

Comment: I don't understand your use of inheritance – or for that matter, classes – at all. For starters, ``self`` seems to be only used to ferry around what should be *parameters* to the methods – you even say yourself that they should be passed to the methods. Furthermore, if ``openWordlist`` exists solely to feed ``scanDomain``, then the class with the *former* should inherit from the one with the latter, or at the very least the base class should define both. Overall it seems as if you shouldn't be using classes at all, but just functions or generators.

Answer (score 1):

The name of your input file is `''`, which can't be opened.
Thus, you never set `self.word` to anything except `''`.
And even if you did open a file, you would only set `self.word` to the last word in the file.

Do what you say you want to do; "loop through a wordlist file in the parent class method `openWordlist()`, and for every word in that wordlist file, pass it to the [...] method `scanDomain()`"

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.wordlistFile = filename
    
    def scanDomain(self, word):
        pass
    
    def openWordlist(self):
        with open(self.wordlistFile, 'r') as suppliedWordlist:
            for word in suppliedWordlist:
                self.scanDomain(word.strip())
                

class DirectoryScan(Main):

    def scanDomain(self, word):
        try:
            self.cleanURL = 'https://google.com/' + word
            self.reqURL = requests.get(self.cleanURL)
            if self.reqURL.status_code == 200:
                print('Found: {self.cleanURL}')
            elif self.reqURL.status_code != 200:
                pass
        except InvalidURL:
                print(f'{self.targetURL} does NOT exist.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = DirectoryScan('somefile.txt')
    d.openWordlist()
```

(The point of this inheritance structure is a mystery, though.)

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue is here:

```
def openWordlist(self):
    with open(self.wordlistFile, 'r') as suppliedWordlist:
        for word in suppliedWordlist:
            word = word.strip()
            self.word = word
```

You are iterating over the suppliedWordList and set self.word = word.
But from the context I get, the suppliedWordList can be longer. So maybe your last line does not contain what you actually want to add there to your url.